# How do I set one background image as the box in which each post is set on a tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I have decided to take on a more difficult goal for my custom tumblr themes, and I want to make it so that there is a background image for each post, like in other themes each one is set in a box, I was wondering if there were a way to make that box into an image.

I have fiddled with ready-made themes to see if I could copy the part that does what I want, but I cannot identify the code that dictates this, nor do I know for sure that these themes even implement the type of thing I would like to do.

I have no been able to find questions similar to mine (if you have, feel free to point me in their direction)

Other than this, it is a fairly simple 2-column theme.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to go into more detail with your question so we can help you specifically however from having created tumblr themes in the past the easiest way of doing it is by putting each post in its own `DIV` and assigning it CSS as below

**Theme Code**

```
<div id="post">
 {block:Posts}
                {block:Text}
                    <li class="post text">
                        {block:Title}
                            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                        {/block:Title}

                        {Body}
                    </li>
                {/block:Text}

                {block:Photo}
                    <li class="post photo">
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>

                        {block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                {/block:Photo}

                {block:Panorama}
                    <li class="post panorama">
                        {LinkOpenTag}
                            <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                        {LinkCloseTag}

                        {block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                {/block:Panorama}

                {block:Photoset}
                    <li class="post photoset">
                        {Photoset-500}

                        {block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                {/block:Photoset}

                {block:Quote}
                    <li class="post quote">
                        "{Quote}"

                        {block:Source}
                            <div class="source">{Source}</div>
                        {/block:Source}
                    </li>
                {/block:Quote}

                {block:Link}
                    <li class="post link">
                        <a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>

                        {block:Description}
                            <div class="description">{Description}</div>
                        {/block:Description}
                    </li>
                {/block:Link}

                {block:Chat}
                    <li class="post chat">
                        {block:Title}
                            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                        {/block:Title}

                        <ul class="chat">
                            {block:Lines}
                                <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                                    {block:Label}
                                        <span class="label">{Label}</span>
                                    {/block:Label}

                                    {Line}
                                </li>
                            {/block:Lines}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {/block:Chat}

                {block:Video}
                    <li class="post video">
                        {Video-500}

                        {block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                {/block:Video}

                {block:Audio}
                    <li class="post audio">
                        {AudioPlayerBlack}

                        {block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                {/block:Audio}
            {/block:Posts}
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#post {

background-image:url('paper.gif');

}
```

As i said I hope that can be of some help to you but it is hard without you being more specific.

If you get stuck on the theme you can always refer back to here, posting your code or visit this link: [Creating a custom HTML Tumblr Theme](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)